I transfered coins to a neiro address but the contract addresses are different, can i retrieve my coins?
Token was transfered from one exchange to another but I later discover they are not of the same contract information even though they share the same network/block chain.
Can I retrieve such tokens?

Can you share the transaction hash and addresses involved? A token symbol may not be unique. Some exchanges use its own naming scheme.

No that's not possible because it's not the same contract .I think the token's are lost.
